# Python program EOF error with inputs

Tags: python

I have been trying to convert my code from java to python and I come across this issue. I am trying to make a calendar and everything I input the month and year, I come across this issue that I do not know what is means.

May you guys help me out?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbook/Documents/Untitled.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/macbook/Documents/Untitled.py", line 30, in main
    m, y = eval(input("Enter the month, and year (separated by spaces): "))
  File "<string>", line 1
    12 2013
          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

My code:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
def isLeapYear():
    if((year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)):
        return true
    else:
        return false

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
def dayOfWeek(mon, day, year):
    if(mon < 3):
        year = year-1

    wy = 3 + year + (year/4) - (year/100) + (year/400)
    wm = int(2.6 * ((mon+9 % 12) +0.5))
    wd = day-1
    return (wd + wm + wy) % 7

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
def daysInMonth(month, year):
    if(month ==4 or month ==6 or month ==9 or month==11):
        return 30
    elif(month==2):
        if(isLeapYear(year)):
            return 29
        else:
            return 28
    else:
        return 31

def main():
    m, y = eval(input("Enter the month, and year (separated by spaces): "))
    print("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat\n")
    i=0
    while(i<dayOfWeek(m,1,y)):
        print("     ")
        i=i+1

    d=1
    while(d <= daysInMonth(m,y)):
        print(d)
        if(dayOfWeek(m,d,y) == 6):
            print("\n")
        d=d+1

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

`eval()` only takes valid Python expressions. `12 2013` is not a valid Python expression.

Either require that the numbers are separated by a comma (`'12, 2013'`) or use a different method of parsing the date input.

Try to avoid `eval()` for parsing input; a user with less friendly intent could enter arbitrary code to mess up your program and hijack the process when you do that.

The following line would work just as well for your purposes:

```
m, y = map(int, input("Enter the month, and year (separated by spaces): ").split())
```

Comment: thanks! however, after i fixed that issue my dates won't print out when i compile my program. i can't seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: @user3002936: your `dayOfWeek(m,1,y)` call never varies, so there is an infinite loop there.

Comment: oh okay, and i fixed that but it still doesn't print like a calendar should do. how do i print System.out.printf("%-5d", d) in python? im getting stuck there.

Comment: You can use [`str.format()` formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) (new style): `print(format(d, '-5d'))`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is obviously here:

```
m, y = eval(input("Enter the month, and year (separated by spaces): "))
```

You seems to have entered the string `12 2013` and you ask Python to eval it. But, `12 2013` means nothings in Python (it's just two integers separeted by a space). You can

- Add a comma between number, `12, 2013` and it'll worked with the same code
- Ask numbers with two call of `input`

For security matters, you should implement the second solution.